# Substracting rows in different files

Tags: python, date, time, difference

I am selecting several csv file in a folder. Each file has a "Time" Column.
I would like to plot an additional column called time duration which substract the time of each row with the first row and this for each file
What should I add in my code?

```
strong textoutput = pd.DataFrame()
for name in list_files_log:
    with folder.get_download_stream(name) as f:
        try:
            tmp = pd.read_csv(f)
            tmp["sn"] = get_sn(name)
            tmp["filename"]= os.path.basename(name)
            output = output.append(tmp)
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `Time` column would look like this:

```
                 Time
0 2015-02-04 02:10:00
1 2016-03-05 03:30:00
2 2017-04-06 04:40:00
3 2018-05-07 05:50:00
```

You could create `Duration` column using:

```
df['Duration'] = df['Time'] - df['Time'][0]
```

And you'd get:

```
                 Time           Duration
0 2015-02-04 02:10:00    0 days 00:00:00
1 2016-03-05 03:30:00  395 days 01:20:00
2 2017-04-06 04:40:00  792 days 02:30:00
3 2018-05-07 05:50:00 1188 days 03:40:00
```